Mongo db unique index on sub document problem
I have a collection estates with a unique index on the name field, created thus:
db.estates.createIndex ({ "name": 1 }, { unique: true })

This works - attempts to insert a duplicate name cause an error.
I try to create a per estate unique index on the buildings sub-document (an array of different buildings):
db.estates.createIndex ({ "name": 1, "buildings.name": 1 }, { unique: true })

This does not work; I can have numerous name: 'Building 1' on my buildings sub document for my name: 'Estate 1' document.
Sample document:
{
_id: ObjectId('6661f5ec5236ce287fa26a17'),
name: 'Estate 1',
code: '12345',
buildings: [
  { name: 'Building 3' },
  {
    name: 'Building 4',
    code: '4444',
    function: '',
    floor_area: '',
    number_of_floors: '',
    _id: ObjectId('66673d5ae5d0c8f632280614')
  },
  {
    name: 'All buildings',
    _id: ObjectId('66ae5a9fc029cb808ff01784')
  },
  {
    name: 'Building 2',
    code: '222222',
    function: '',
    floor_area: '',
    number_of_floors: '',
    _id: ObjectId('66afaaee36c6939cbbe20611')
  },
  {
    name: 'Building 1',
    code: '',
    function: '',
    floor_area: '',
    number_of_floors: '',
    _id: ObjectId('6739f3d0858859fdada218ea')
  },
  {
    name: 'Building 1',
    code: '',
    function: '',
    floor_area: '',
    number_of_floors: '',
    _id: ObjectId('6739f3e3858859fdada218eb')
  }
],
building_systems: [
  {
    name: 'VS01',
    category: 'Heating - radiator',
    building: 'Building one',
    room: '4320',
    floor: '04',
    control_cabinet: 'AS01',
    year: 2008,
    components: [
      { name: 'P1', category: 'Pump - circulation' },
      { name: 'ST21', category: 'Actuator - valve' }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId('6661f5ec5236ce287fa26a15'),
    name: 'VV01',
    category: 'Hot water',
    building: 'Building one',
    room: '4320',
    floor: '04',
    year: 2008
  },
  { name: 'LB01', _id: ObjectId('66675021e5d0c8f632280615') }
],
control_cabinets: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId('6661f5ec5236ce287fa26a16'),
    name: 'AS01',
    building: 'Building one',
    room: '4320',
    floor: '04',
    year: 2008,
    plc_manufacturer: 'Beckhoff',
    ip_address: '198.192.0.28',
    port: 183,
    protocol: 'ADSL'
  },
  { name: 'AS02', _id: ObjectId('66675442e5d0c8f632280618') }
],

What am I missing?

Do you have sample documents?

I've added a sample document, you can see two buildings with the name  'Building 1'

That's just one document. Show us a second one, where you expect it should violate the unique index. A single document is always unique, of course.

You misunderstand, I want the unique index on the SUB-document; I want to constrain the document so I cannot have two buildings with the same name in a single document.

The index works the way it was intended but not the way you expected.
The index is per document so the estates collection can only have 1 document with name: 'Estate 1' and buildings.name: 'Building 1'. When you insert a new document a check is made for another document that would have that combination, not if the document with name: 'Estate 1' has another array element containing buildings.name: 'Building 1'.
So these documents can't both exist in the same collection:
// estates
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a11"),
    "name": "Estate 1",
    "buildings": [
       { "name": "Building 1" }, 
    ],
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a12"),
    "name": "Estate 1",
    "buildings": [
       { "name": "Building 1" }, 
    ],
}

But these documents can:
// estates
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a11"),
    "name": "Estate 1",
    "buildings": [
       { "name": "Building 1" }, 
       { "name": "Building 1" },
       { "name": "Building 1" }
    ],
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a12"),
    "name": "Estate 2",
    "buildings": [
       { "name": "Building 2" }, 
       { "name": "Building 2" },
       { "name": "Building 2" }
    ],
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a13"),
    "name": "Estate 1",
    "buildings": [
       { "name": "Building 2" }, 
       { "name": "Building 3" },
       { "name": "Building 4" },
       { "name": "Building 4" }
    ],
}

You might want to consider storing the buildings in another collection with the parent Estate._id stored as a reference. Then you could do an index on that new collection like:
db.buildings.createIndex({ "estateId": 1, "name": 1 }, { unique: true });

When you create a new document in the new buildings collection, this new index would ensure that only one document exists with name: 'Building 1' and the estateId being a reference to the estates document _id value that has the name: 'Estate 1'.
// estates
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a11"),
    "name": "Estate 1",
    "buildings": [
       ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a14"), 
    ],
},

// buildings
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a14"),
    "estateId": ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a11"),
    "name": "Building 1"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a15"),
    "estateId": ObjectId("65494baa21b99c8cff188a11"), // ❌ E11000 duplicate key error
    "name": "Building 1" // ❌ E11000 duplicate key error
},


That would mean your Estate.buildings array would just be an array of ObjectIds instead of sub-documents. You can do a $lookup to join them like this.

Hmm, I understand your answer, the explanation of the indexing is very helpful, and I like this answer up to a point, but then it starts to feel like a SQL database exercise (which I'm hoping to get away from)

In my case, it will be easier to scan the document for duplicates when I get put/post for buildings etc; I think this will be the way forward :) thanks again for your help :)

If you want to keep sub-documents then yes you would need to programmatically handle the duplication integrity checks. By that I mean use a validator to check the buildings array and name keys on insertion or query the database first. It sound like you already know that so happy to be of help.

You are correct in your instincts. This normalisation of the data is similar to how you would do in an RDBMS but there are no cascade-on-deletes, foreign key/primary key integrity checks etc so you have to handle that yourself. NoSQL databases offer great flexibility. However, you have to choose the right database for your project. I have leaned to compromise and optimise where I can

Following @jQueeny's explanation, I implemented the following (posted in case useful for others):
const estate = await db.collection('estates').findOne({ name: req.params.estateName });
if (!estate) {
  return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Estate not found' });
}

// Check asset of this name does not already exist
if (estate[assetType] && estate[assetType].find (el => el.name === req.body.name)) {
  return res.status(409)
    .json({ error: `An entry with name ${req.body.name} already exists in ${assetType}` });
}

let insertObj = {};
insertObj[assetType] = req.body;

const result = await db.collection('estates').updateOne(
  { name: req.params.estateName },
  { $push: insertObj }
);
if (result.matchedCount === 0) {
  return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Estate not found' });
}
res.status(201).json(req.body);

